# Fire triggers in replica nodes (cassandra)

Tags: cassandra, triggers, replication

I am using a Cassandra 4-node cluster with full replication in all nodes.

I have defined a trigger on a table. However, when I update a row in this table, trigger is fired only on the local node.

Is there any way to fire this trigger in all nodes (based on replication)?

Comment: What does the trigger do? Can replication be responsible for propagating the results of the trigger to the other nodes?

Comment: The trigger is only used for notifying the application for data changes. The trigger does not update/delete/insert the data in cassandra in any way.

Comment: Welcome @NefHal, don't be shy editing your question with additional information. You can always add an additional comment '@user' who asks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers run on the coordinator before they are passed off on be applied. To see it on a per replica the best way is to use [CDC](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/cdc.html) (which is also more reliable than triggers) and follow the changes as they are flushed to commitlog.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have seen some comments though saying that CDC does not always guarantee order, as segments are not always moved in the exact order they have been created ( https://dzone.com/articles/cassandra-to-kafka-data-pipeline-part-2). Is this valid? And if so, how could I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

With CDC you have to solve another problems:

- validate order of the pockets, since it is not guaranteed
- make tradeoff between single point of failure vs implementing tool for CDC logs duplication checker, let me explain: 
  You either enable CDC logging on one node and this will become your bottleneck. Or you enable CDC on all nodes and then you have to somehow manage data duplication since leader will send logs to repications.

You can deploy triggers on every node of your cluster. It won't cause any data duplication and works perfectly fine.